# Excel scatter chart showing dates before and after dates in dataset

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a CSV file containing temperature and humidity readings for a date range that I'm charting with a scatter chart. The first date in the data set is 03-Mar-2019 and the last is 09-Mar-2019. Once I chart this data I get a chart that starts on 02-Mar-2019 and ends on 11-Mar-2019.

[Example of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOq5B.png)

How do I make the chart run edge to edge without these two additional empty days?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried formatting the axis?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up some data to look similar to yours and played around with it until the dates showed up correctly. For the cells that contained the source dates, I formatted them to type Date. Then I created the chart as an XY Scatter with two data series as you did.

If you right click on the horizontal axis and select Format Axis, you can change the way Excel interprets/displays the data. I made the following changes:
-Axis Options/Bounds: Excel converted the dates to numbers. I noticed that the difference between the max and min was equal to the number of vertical gridlines on the chart, so I just added 1 to the min and subtracted 1 from the max. That got rid of the extra spaces on the ends.
-Number/Category: Select "Date"

Note: This is Excel 2016

[image]